# Saving a txt file as a delimited csv file in R

Tags: r, export-to-csv

I have the following code to read a file and save it as a csv file, I remove the first 7 lines in the text file and then the 3rd column as well, since I just require the first two columns.

```
 current_file <- paste("Experiment 1 ",i,".cor",sep="")
 curfile <- list.files(pattern = current_file)
 curfile_data <- read.table(curfile, header=F,skip=7,sep=",")
 curfile_data <- curfile_data[-grep('V3',colnames(curfile_data))]
 write.csv(curfile_data,curfile)
 new_file <- paste("Dev_C",i,".csv",sep="")
 new_file 
 file.copy(curfile, new_file)
```

The curfile thus hold two column variables V1 and V2 along with the observation number column in the beginning.

Now when I use file.copy to copy the contents of the curfile into a .csv file and then open the new .csv file in Excel, all the data seems to be concatenated and appear in a single column, is there a way to show each of the individual columns separately? Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

---

The data in the .txt file looks like this,

```
"","V1","V2","V3"
"1",-0.02868862,5.442283e-11,76.3
"2",-0.03359281,7.669754e-12,76.35
"3",-0.03801883,-1.497323e-10,76.4
"4",-0.04320051,-6.557672e-11,76.45
"5",-0.04801207,-2.557059e-10,76.5
"6",-0.05325544,-9.986231e-11,76.55
```

Comment: the easiest would be to give the file a `.csv` extension.  otherwise you used to be able to (but don't have Excel at the moment) somehow get it to bring up the import options, allowing you to say that it's really a comma separated file

Comment: If I understand it correct, you're asking how to get Excel to show this file correctly. If so, I suggest you edit the tags to Excel and not R.
To answer your question though, in Excel, you can specify the delimiter under data > text to columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Text to columns` feature in Excel, selecting comma as a delimiter. The position of this point in menu depends on version of Excel you are using.